# Does String's toString() method have any practical purpose?

Tags: java, string, tostring

I was reading [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29) and noticed it. Never imaginated it. The description:

> This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.

Besides filling conventions or using computing resources, what does a `.toString()` in Java do on a `String` that using the `String` itself wouldn't? Why doesn't it simply inherit the `.toString()` from class `java.lang.Object`?

EDIT:

I understand that in situations of polymorphism an own `toString()` method has to exist since it overrode its parent's `toString()`. What I want to know in the first question is if there is any situation where you'll get something different between using `stringVariable`/`"String value"` and using `stringVariable.toString()`/`"String value".toString()`.

Ex. gr.: An output operation like `System.out.println(stringVariable.toString());` or a value assignment like `stringVariable = "String value".toString();`.

Comment: Hi there. In case you don't see it after your suspension is lifted, there is a comment from JohnDoDo on Jon's answer. FWIW, if you return, please do consider reinstating all of the unaccepted answers - if they were good enough to accept at the time, those helpful people are being punished for an event outside of their control.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Besides filling conventions or using computing resources, what does a .toString() in Java do on a String that using the String itself wouldn't?

It means it gives an appropriate result when called polymorphically.

> Why doesn't it simply inherit the .toString() from class java.lang.Object?

Because that wouldn't give the same result, and almost certainly not the *desired* result.

`Object.toString()` is meant to give a reasonably useful string representation of the object. The `Object` implementation gives information about the type and a value which can be used for crude identity hints (diagnostically useful, but that's all). That's clearly *not* the most useful string representation for a string - the string itself is.

While I *would* say that it's a pity that `toString` is defined in quite a woolly way (it's not clear whether the result is meant for machine, developer or user consumption), it feels obvious to me that a `String` would return itself in the implementation.

Comment: Effective Java item 10 discusses some reasons to avoid fully specifying `toString()`: because someone will _inevitably_ decide it's a good idea to parse it.

Comment: @TrevorTrovalds: Doesn't the documentation already answer that? It returns "this object" - so no, there's no situation where using `foo` and `foo.toString()` will give a different result where `foo` is a non-null reference to a `String`.

Comment: @TrevorTrovalds: Um, ish - although I *wouldn't* use it for that purpose.

Comment: @Trevor... I'm scratching my head trying to envision a scenario where throwing a NPE with `str.toString()` would be better than a `if str == null` check...

Comment: @user985358: Trevor, you recently unaccepted this answer as well as others. Is it something wrong with this answer or the others or had you other reasons to unnaccept so many answers?

Comment: @JohnDoDo: the OP may not see your comment there, since they have no comments in this thread (they may have deleted them since you posted). I'll put a note on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Practical example:

```
public abstract class MetadataProcessor {

protected void processMetadata() {    
   Map<String, Object> metadata = getMetadata();
   for(String key : metadata.keySet()) {
      if(metadata.get(key) instanceof Date) {
      processDate(metadata.get(key));
   } else { //String or any other object type
      processString(metadata.get(key).toString());
   }
}

private void processDate(Date date) {
   (...)
}

private void processString(String string) {
   (...)
}

/**
* contains document's metadata, values must be String or Date
**/
protected abstract Map<String, Object> getMetadata();
}
```

If String's .toString() wouldn't return the String itself, an additional `if(foo instanceof String)` would be needed in above code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public final class String
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

All object has `toString()` method (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString() ). `String` is a type of object, therefore, it also need a method `toString()` for implementing method from its base class.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously old, but another answer that avoids the need of (foo instanceof String) is when dealing with generics.

It'd be annoying to get a string representation of every object, but then string is the odd man out requiring extra code to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `toString` method in java is done by overriding the `Object`'s `toString` method. The java `toString()` method is used when we need a string representation of an object. It is defined in `Object` class. This method can be overridden to customize the `String` representation of the `Object`.