# Effect of invoking toString() method on String object

Tags: java

I have a String object in my code like

```
String tempString = "Some String";
```

now if I write something as

```
tempString.toString();
```

will this create another String object in String pool?

Comment: Just as a comment, the Java API source code is widely available, so you can always look into the sources if you have some doubt about the internal behaviour of the API. In most cases, they are bundeled in a file called src.zip in your JDK, or you can lookup the class name in Google...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because `toString()` method in class `String` looks like this one:

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Andremoniy from the code. Here is the part from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29)

> toString
>
> public String toString()
>
> ```
> This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
>
> Specified by:
>     toString in interface CharSequence
> Overrides:
>     toString in class Object
>
> Returns:
>     the string itself.
> ```

So no new object is created in this case. Regarding the use, it's just extra piece of code you are adding and nothing else.

Other interesting read in this respect

1. [Java: does String's toString() method have any practical purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11386398/1135954)
2. [How to use the toString method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3615721/1135954)